# stripping properties and personal information from .odt files on linux?

Tags: linux, properties, odt

I have a few files that have fields of properties and personal information that I want to remove, the format is **.odt**. Basically, I want to strip out everything. What utilities are available for the job on **Linux**?

Comment: .odt is compressed set of files, so you can unzip it and edit .xml files, it's not convenient, but it's a possibility. Most info in file meta.xml and content.xml.

Comment: You may delete it manually for every file with libreoffice.

Comment: @FSMaxB could you explain, how?

Comment: @naxa I'm using a german localisation, so I don't know how it's actually called, but if you go to something like "File" -> "Properties" you can edit the metadata.

Comment: @FSMaxB I see thank you! :) I understood the menus, but can only also expect it to be called like this - since I use a Hungarian localization! :D Time to install the English one for me...